# How call a function in another process (C , Linux)

Tags: c, ipc, embedded-linux

Im debugging an application A and i have found that when process A (application A) call function foo() this function is located in another process B. I mean that if i kill process B before foo() is called then foo() output is not showed. I can modify foo() code and see the new modification when foo() is called from application A. Both applications have foo() defined. I dont know how this can be achieved. The call is performed in a normal way at compilation time:

```
....
foo(b);
....
```

Comment: In Linux, there is no way for a process to call a function in another process, at least not directly.  Maybe you should explain the architecture which might make this possible.

Comment: I see a reference to application B in the Makefile of application A:     

    ifeq ($(CONFIG_USE_SHARED_LIB),y)
    UPNPDIR  = ../mini_upnp
    UPNPINC  = $(UPNPDIR)
    CFLAGS += -I$(UPNPINC)

mini_upnp is the folder of the application B where is located foo()

Comment: I am having trouble following you, but I think you might be mistaking a call into a library as a call across processes.  Please read about the concept of a ["process"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) and see if you need to rephrase your question.

Comment: You can call functions in another process: gdb is able to do this since ever. A highly non-trivial amount of ptrace() magic will definitely be required. :)

Answer (score 0):

gdb can more or less do it for you. You just need several gdb sessions, one for each process (if those are on embedded target, gdb-server will help). Then break into one of the processes in the convenient location (using breakpoint, or script, or whatever) and use "call foo()" statement.

For example:

```
(gdb) call fprintf(stderr, "test %d\n", 5)
test 5
$3 = 7
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i realize that i was calling foo() from shared library. I guessed that foo() was running inside process B because process B is needed for correct execution of foo(). My apoligizes.